# HTML fixed header bar when scroll

Tags: html, css, css-position

I've written an example here

http://jsfiddle.net/R9Lds/

I want a header bar on the top of the page.

```
<p style="vertical-align: middle; color: white">Head Bar</p>
```

And when user scrolls down and up, the header bar will always be on the top.

But now it has an issue that the bottom of the page will be cut-off.

Just like the example above, the

"Title 3",

"Content 3.",

"Author: Alex"

will be cut-off.

Anyone has any ideas about this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Eric

Comment: The fiddle you've posted is a bit chaotic. What I'd do is scour the internet for some template examples and go from there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You actually can achieve it simpler than that. You only need to set your header div with `position: fixed`, and a 'push' div to, well... push the content down.

Take a look in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JwS49/)

Comment: I [modified this slightly](https://jsfiddle.net/vd4uL78y/5/) so you don't have to repeat the offset size.  Does this break any rules or is it a valid way to reduce the duplication of `30px`?

Comment: Nice, it's surely a better practice of **DRY** :)

Answer (score 3):

You should set your header bar to `position: fixed` instead.

Example:

```
div.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

if you are concerned about the top of .home being cut off, you can also add a margin-top

http://jsfiddle.net/R9Lds/1/