# Add fixed header to li with scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have list on my page. There are li elements with height 30% and add vertical scrollbar. In every li is header with some text. How can i remain this header when i scroll block?

```
<ul id="groupedTasksUl">
 <li class="groupedTasksMainLi" style="width: 30%; height: 30vh;">

<div class="groupedTaskHeader"><h1>{$task_type}</h1></div>

  <ul class="innerUL">
   ....
  </ul>

 </li>
</ul>
```

When i scroll  .groupedTasksMainLi  i need  remain .groupedTaskHeader on top. How can i solve this ? Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24878582/html-fixed-header-bar-when-scroll

Answer (score 0):

> How can i remain this header when i scroll block?

If you don`t need IE support, you can upply follow properties to header element

```
position: sticky;
top: 0;
```

Comment: yes, it has fixed position, but i need that this header will be always visible:
https://clip2net.com/s/43gR0v4

Comment: Then may be `position: relative` for parent element. And `position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%;` for header. It is difficult to offer something without seeing a real example.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to add `position: sticky;` to the .groupedTaskHeader class, as below:

```
.groupedTaskHeader {
    position: -webkit-sticky; /* for Safari */
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
```

You can find more about positioning here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

// Edit:
Referring to your comment under a different answer you can simply add the background to the header:

```
<ul id="groupedTasksUl">
  <li class="groupedTasksMainLi" style="width: 30%; height: 30vh;">
    <div class="groupedTaskHeader"><h1>Title 1</h1></div>
    <ul class="innerUL">
      <li>Li 1</li>
      <li>Li 2</li>
      <li>Li 3</li>
      <li>Li 4</li>
      <li>Li 5</li>
      <li>Li 6</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
...
```

And in CSS:

```
.groupedTaskHeader {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: white;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0qb84ktr/